# Does Google Compute Engine support making aiohttp get requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, discord, google-compute-engine, python-asyncio, aiohttp

So I'm trying to make a discord bot that checks a website and sends a message if the price of an item falls below a certain price. I got it working on my local machine, so I decided to host it on Google Compute Engine so it can run 24/7, but I ran into some issues.

After much testing, I've determined it's because Google Compute Engine doesn't like making aiohttp GET requests. Below is the isolated part of my code that is causing issues on Google Compute Engine, but works fine on my local machine.

```
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import aiohttp

async def myDriver():
    await httpReq()


async def httpReq():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16824569005?Item=N82E16824569005&cm_sp=Homepage_BS-_-P1_24-569-005-_-12062020") as page:
            pageContent = await page.text()
            content = BeautifulSoup(pageContent, 'lxml')
            price = content.find("li", {"class": "price-current"}).strong.text.replace(",", "")
            print(price)


asyncio.run(myDriver())
```

Error:

```
File "GCEtestAiohttp.py", line 19, in httpReq
    price = content.find("li", {"class": "price-current"}).strong.text.replace(",", "") AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strong'
```

notes:

- "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
- python 3.7.3
- aiohttp 3.6.3
- I've tried similar code with the normal requests library on Google Compute Engine, and everything works fine, so I really believe its an issue with using aiohttp requests.

Comment: What is contained in `content` at the time you perform the find?

Comment: Ah I see, its a recaptcha.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>
   Are you a human?
  </title>
.
.
.
grecaptcha.ready(function()

Do you know if there is a way around this, and what is the reason that I encounter a recaptcha via aiohttp and not requests?

Comment: It may not be possible.  Remember, the idea behind recaptcha and other similar checks might be to prevent exactly what you are trying to do.  It feels like you are working on a "robot" that scans web pages and when ever I see recaptcha, the name of the story is to prove "you are not a robot".

Comment: Additionally I would recommend you to check the user agent that you are using to make this request. But yes, as stated in the comment above, websites protected by recaptcha are trying to avoid specifically activities like this (automated actions)

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for the advice people. I just thought it was weird because I was able to do so with requests just fine but I had issues with aiohttp.